# Type error: not supported between instances of INT and STR

Tags: python, typeerror

Hey I am trying to build a program for an assignment and I can't seem to get my head around functions. I keep getting a type error and I am not sure if I am even close. Can I ask for some help please?

```
valListInt = [23, 2, 34, 23, 43, 22, 32, 32, 43, 34]
valListChar = ['c', 'a', 'x', '#', 'T', '1', '6', 'A', '%', 'b']
valListDbl = [23.3847239, 2.3974, 34.183734, 23.0, 43.36381, 22.3, 32.0, 32.1919, 43.938363, 34.38364]

i = 0


list = [valListInt, valListChar, valListDbl]

def sort(x):
    list = len(x)
    for i in range(list):
        for j in range((i+1),list):
            if x[i] > x[j]:
                list = x[i]
                x[i] = x[j]
                x[j] = list
    print(x)                
sort(list)
```

Comment: You're currently trying to sort a list of lists. Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: You're using the name `list` for two entirely different purposes inside your function, which are going to conflict with each other - and both uses are horribly, horribly inappropriate, because `list` is a fundamental built-in Python type.

Comment: Thanks!
I changed that around and got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to arise from the comparison of `valListChar` with the other two lists. I get the feeling that you were trying to encode a list of chars on the line:

```py
valListChar = ['c', 'a', 'x', '#', 'T', '1', '6', 'A', '%', 'b']
```

Python doesn't have a `char` type builtin, unlike other languages like C++; all single characters are encoded as strings, even if you enclose them with single quotes. `valListChar` therefore consists of an array of single-length strings, which Python doesn't know how to compare with numerical values. Thus, when the code is executed, the line

```py
if x[i] > x[j]
```

will throw a TypeError.

I can't give much else as I'm not entirely sure about the details of your assignment; however, if you want to convert the characters in `valListChar` to numbers which *can* be compared to the values in `valListInt` and `valListDbl`, the [ord](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ord-function-python/) function may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Ike, the goal was to sort each of the lists and I was stuck with getting my head around how to do that with strings and integers.

I think I have it now and it works.
Appreciate the help.